# Install-ADDSDomainController Hangs

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code to promote DCs.  I get several warning as expected and no errors however it hangs after the warning "A delegation for this DNS server cannot be created because the authoritive parent zone cannot be found.

Powershell appears to be trying these 2 options "Determining replication source DC" and "Configuring the local computer to host Active Directory Domain Services" as seen in this image. [Powershell Warnings and Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlmbC.png)

```
 Write-Host "`nPromoting Server to a DC..."
        $Error.Clear()     
    
        #Get Domain name
        $domain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
        
        #Promote DC
 #Promote DC
        try {
            Install-ADDSDomainController `
                -NoGlobalCatalog:$false `
                -CreateDnsDelegation:$false `
                -Credential (Get-Credential) `
                -CriticalReplicationOnly:$false `
                -DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
                -DomainName $domain `
                -InstallDns:$true `
                -LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
                -NoRebootOnCompletion:$false `
                -SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" `
                -Force:$true
        }
        catch { #Not all errors are getting caught here
            Write-Host "`n`nThere was an error promting DC!" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host "`nReview error below and rerun script:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Read-Host "Press any key to continue..."
            Write-Host "`n $error"
            Exit
        }
```

Comment: With `-CriticalReplicationOnly:$false`, `Install-ADDSDomainController` will attempt full inbound directory replication to build out/populate its database replicas. How big is the smallest `NTDS.dit` file on your existing DCs? :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the login name.

It requires **domain\username** when entering the credentials.

If you do not include the domain will start and perform some of the promotion tasks, but eventually will hang.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).